# My Shuttle XPC Win 7 64 Bit sounds like it boots, but has no video signal

Tags: graphics-card

I need suggestions on how to proceed.  I really just don't know where to start.

Can I force onboard video?  I don't get any video signal, regardless of the output I use.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't get any video output you would normally need to rely on any beeps emitted during the POST sequence. Does the computer make any beeps while booting? If so, how many?

You may also be able to force the on-board video adapter via a BIOS setting, which you will need to check the manual/documentation for.

Comment: and just to cover your basics - check monitor and video cable, and if possible replace vga card with a working replacement or test the current one in another environment.

Comment: No beeps, No apparent POST.  Just sounds of HDD and Fans running.  I will try a different video card, but I can't get to BIOS to change settings.